# Check if the child page has sibling pages, and bookmark current page

Tags: pages, wp-list-pages

I already check if the secondary page has sister pages and I show it in a list of sister pages within each secondary page, but when I am inside a sister page, in the list where I show it I want to make the page where it is located be marked.

Something like this:

```
Science books
  Book 1 
  Book 2
  Book 3
```

When I'm inside:

```
Book 2
```

In the list of books I want to mark the current page

```
Book 1
Aqual page: Book 2
Book 3
```

Is it possible?
Thank you in advance

---

**EDIT**: I currently display the list of sibling pages within each sub-page as follows:

```
<?php
    global $post; 
    if ( $post->post_parent ) {  
        $siblings = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post_parent' => $post->post_parent,
            'post__not_in' => array( $post->ID )
        ) );
    }

    if ( $siblings->have_posts() ) :
?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $siblings->have_posts() ) : $siblings->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></li>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible:

```
<?php
    global $post;
    $current_post = $post;
    if ( $post->post_parent ) {  
        $siblings = new WP_Query( array(
            'post_type' => 'page',
            'order' => 'ASC',
            'post_parent' => $post->post_parent
        ) );
    }

    if ( $siblings->have_posts() ) :
?>
    <ul>
        <?php while ( $siblings->have_posts() ) : $siblings->the_post(); ?>
        <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            <?php if ( $current_post->ID == $post->ID ) echo 'Actual page: '; ?>
            <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a></li>
        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I have tried the code in what I have right now but it doesn't show me anything, I may not have added it in the right place. I just edited the question, I added how I currently display the list of sibling pages within each sub-page. 
I added the code you provided me with inside: 
`if ( $siblings->have_posts() ) { 
  // Here
}`

Comment: I've updated my answer using your code.

Comment: It was for some nonsense that didn't work, thank you so much for your help!